# Codename One - class [Ljava.lang.Object cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Double;

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to work out how to save and load in codename one. Here is a barebones example of my code:

```
public class Calcuator {

Double[] regValues;

public Calcuator() {
    this.regValues = (Double[])Storage.getInstance().readObject("regValueStack");
    if (this.regValues == null) {
            this.regValues = new Double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    }

}
```

This is how I'm writing to memory:

```
/// some code that edited the array in the 'myCalculator' instance of Calculator class
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("regValueStack", myCalculator.regValues);
```

This worked when my array was null and I manually initalized it. However, after writing it to memory once, whenever I try to read it in the constructor I get this error:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

Can you help me understand and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Storage serialization only supports object arrays. Due to the lack of reflection we can't create a `Double` array dynamically. So when you write a `Double[]` it will be returned as `Object[]`.

There's a special case for primitive arrays so `double[]` might work as expected.

Alternatively you can just do:

```java
Object[] temp = Storage.getInstance().readObject("regValueStack");
if(temp != null) {
    this.regValues = new Double[temp.length];
    System.copyarray(temp, 0, temp.length, this.regValues, 0);
}
```